# Evaluating one integral in terms of another

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $$S=\int_0^1\frac{e^t}{t+1}dt$$then what is the value of :$$\int_{a-1}^a\frac{e^{-t}}{t-a-1}dt$$

The answer is given as $-Se^{-a}$

Comment: **Hint:** Let $u=-t$ and $x=u+a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $t\mapsto -t+a$

So we have $$S=\int_0^1\frac{e^t}{t+1}dt=\int_{a}^{a-1}\frac{e^{-t+a}}{-t+a+1}(-1)dt=e^{a}\int_{a-1}^{a}\frac{e^{-t}}{-t+a+1}dt$$

Now, we just solve for the integral we want.

$$S=e^{a}\int_{a-1}^{a}\frac{e^{-t}}{-t+a+1}dt\Rightarrow\int_{a-1}^{a}\frac{e^{-t}}{t-a-1}dt=(-1)\cdot e^{-a}\cdot S=-Se^{-a}$$

Which is the answer given.